# Пару Ошибок а понять не могу Как их исправить

Tags: python, pycharm, pip

```
 `import cloudinary
from faunadb import query as q
from faunadb.client import FaunaClient
from telegram import (
    ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
)
from telegram.ext import (
    CallbackContext,
    ConversationHandler
)

from config import (
    api_key, api_secret,
    FAUNA_KEY
)

# configure cloudinary
cloudinary.config(
    cloud_name="curiouspaul",
    api_key=api_key,
    api_secret=api_secret
)
# fauna client config
client = FaunaClient (secret=FAUNA_KEY)
# Define Options
CHOOSING, CLASS_STATE, SME_DETAILS, CHOOSE_PREF, \
SME_CAT, ADD_PRODUCTS, SHOW_STOCKS, POST_VIEW_PRODUCTS = range (8)


def start(update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    print ("You called")
    bot = context.bot
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    bot.send_message (
        chat_id=chat_id,
        text="Hi fellow, Welcome to SMEbot ,"
             "Please tell me about yourself, "
             "provide your full name, email, and phone number, "
             "separated by comma each e.g: "
             "John Doe, JohnD@gmail.com, +234567897809"
    )
    return CHOOSING

def choose(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id

    data = update.message.text.split(',')
    if len(data) < 3 or len(data) > 3:
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text="Invalid entry, please make sure to input the details "
            "as requested in the instructions"
        )
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text="Invalid entry, please make sure to input the details "
            "as requested in the instructions"
        )
        bot.send_message(
             chat_id=chat_id,
             text="Type /start, to restart bot"
        )
        return ConversationHandler.END
     # TODO: Check if user already exists before creating new user
      new_user = client.query(
          q.create(q.collection('User'), {
              "data":{
                  "name":data[0],
                  "email":data[1],
                  "telephone":data[2],
                  "is_smeowner":False,
                  "preference": "",
                  "chat_id":chat_id
              }
          })
      )
      context.user_data["user-id"] = new_user["ref"].id()
      context.user_data["user-name"] = data[0]
      context.user_data['user-data'] = new_user['data']
      reply_keyboard = [
      [
          InlineKeyboardButton(
              text="SME",
              callback_data="SME"
          ),
          InlineKeyboardButton(
              text="Customer",
              callback_data="Customer"
          )
      ]
    ]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True)
      bot.send_message(
          chat_id=chat_id,
          text="Collected information succesfully!..?? \n"
          "Which of the following do you identify as ?",
          reply_markup=markup
      )
      return CLASS_STATE


def classer(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    chat_id = update.callback_query.message.chat.id
    name = context.user_data["user-name"]
    if update.callback_query.data.lower() == "sme":
        # update user as smeowner
        client.query(
            q.update(
                q.ref(q.collection("User"), context.user_data["user-id"]),
                {"data": {"is_smeowner":True}}
             )
        )
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text=f"Great! {name}, please tell me about your business, "
            "provide your BrandName, Brand email, Address, and phone number"
            "in that order, each separated by comma(,) each e.g: "
            "JDWears, JDWears@gmail.com, 101-Mike Avenue-Ikeja, +234567897809",
            reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        )
        return SME_DETAILS
    categories = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="Clothing/Fashion",
                callback_data="Clothing/Fashion"
            ),
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="Hardware Accessories",
                callback_data="Hardware Accessories"
            )
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="Food/Kitchen Ware",
                callback_data="Food/Kitchen Ware"
            ),
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="ArtnDesign",
                callback_data="ArtnDesign"
            )
        ]
    ]
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        text="Here's a list of categories available"
        "Choose one that matches your interest",
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(categories)
    )
    return CHOOSE_PREF






    `import handlers
from telegram.ext import (
    CommandHandler, CallbackContext,
    ConversationHandler, MessageHandler,
    Filters, Updater, CallbackQueryHandler
)
from config import TOKEN
updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
print(updater)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
def main():
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', handlers.start)],
        states={
            handlers.CHOOSING: [
                MessageHandler(
                    Filters.all, handlers.choose
                )
            ],
            handlers.CLASS_STATE: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(handlers.classer)
            ]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', handlers.cancel)],
        allow_reentry=True
    )
    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

Вот две Ошибки:line 1, in 
`import handlers`

l`ine 66 new_user = client.query(`
^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Чем они обоснованны я не могу понять

Comment: Ну прочитай на что жалуется

Comment: Я добавил выше!

Comment: Так надо было на добавить, а прочитать! Чтобы понять, на что жалуется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    if len(data) < 3 or len(data) > 3:
    ^
        ...
        return ConversationHandler.END
        ^
     # TODO: Check if user already exists before creating new user
      new_user = client.query(
    ^ ^ ^ 
    | | \ позиция return
    | \ позиция new_user
    \ позиция if
```

Так в Питоне делать нельзя. Комментарии ещё можно сдвигать куда хочешь, хотя это и не желательно, а вот код должен быть либо на той же позиции, что и код выше, либо быть сдвинут на одно и то же число позиций вправо или влево относительно кода выше (либо на число, кратное им, если одновременно закончились несколько блоков кода). А у вас `new_user` находится в промежуточной позиции **между** позициями кода, идущего выше, такое в Питоне не допустимо.

Питон - это язык, где отступы являются не произвольными, а чётко регламентированными.